# Trying to write a stored procedure with start time and end time

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

Im having a db with these tables:

```
drop table if exists events1;
create table if not exists events1(
    time_stamp          decimal(16,6),     
    message             char(90)        not null default 'defult message'
);

drop table if exists events2;
create table if not exists events2(
    time_stamp          decimal(16,6),     
    message             char(90)        not null default 'defult message'
);

drop table if exists events3;
create table if not exists events3(
    time_stamp          decimal(16,6),     
    message             char(90)        not null default 'defult message'
);

insert into events1 (time_stamp,message) values (1485193300,"a1");
insert into events1 (time_stamp,message) values (1485193600,"b1");
insert into events1 (time_stamp,message) values (1485193900,"c1");

insert into events2 (time_stamp,message) values (1485193300,"a1");
insert into events2 (time_stamp,message) values (1485193600,"b2");
insert into events2 (time_stamp,message) values (1485193900,"c3");

insert into events3 (time_stamp,message) values (1485193300,"a1");
insert into events3 (time_stamp,message) values (1485193600,"b2");
insert into events3 (time_stamp,message) values (1485193900,"c3");
```

I'm trying to build a stored procedure, with 3 parameters:

```
start_time (int) (in epoch) 
end_time   (int) (in epoch) 
interval   (int) (in epoch)
```

I wan't that this procedure, will iterate over **start_time**, with step of **interval** till end_time, and on every iteration, to get the union of the three tables, according to the step and interval.

something like:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE get_events
(IN start_time INT,
 IN end_time INT,
 IN interval INT,
)
BEGIN
      while [ start_time <= end_time]
          do
             next_time = start_time + interval
             select * 
             from  events1
             where start_time <= time_stamp and time_stamp <= next_time

             union 

             select * 
             from  events2
             where start_time <= time_stamp and time_stamp <= next_time

             union 

             select * 
             from  events3
             where start_time <= time_stamp and time_stamp <= next_time

             start_time = start_time + interval


      end while

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

i know i have got syntax errors, i don't know how can i return the results and iterate over the union of the 3 tables with the given intervals in the WHERE case.

please advise.

Comment: What do you mean by "return results"?  The `UNION` will return a resultset for each iteration of the `WHILE`.

Answer (score 0):

What are the syntax errors?

`[` is not valid syntax; perhaps `(` in the `WHILE`?

`a = a + b` is not valid syntax; see the `SET` command.

Having 3 tables with identical schema is *usually* a bad design.

Using `CHAR` instead of `VARCHAR` us *usually* a bad idea.

Comment: i wrote the schema just for illustration. i'm stuck at the stored procedure. i wrote the while in their more as a pseudo code, i don't know how to save each iteration's query results, and how to return all the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO "table name"
select * 
   from  events1
   where start_time <= time_stamp and time_stamp <= next_time

   union 

   select * 
   from  events2
   where start_time <= time_stamp and time_stamp <= next_time

   union 

   select * 
   from  events3
   where start_time <= time_stamp and time_stamp <= next_time
```

This will store the query in a table, then you can loop through that table.  Don't know if that's what you were asking for.

Here is the documentation:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html